# Creating Android library project with activities

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I would like to have an Android project which will be a Library Project that holds all my activities and their behaviour, and another Android project which is that actual application that uses the activities from the Library.

What I have done was start a new Android project and I check "Mark as Library" check box. On that project I have one activity.

I've created another Android Project (regular one) and in the project properties I've added the previous project under the projects tab. To that project I then added in the manifest the activity defenition that I copied and pasted from the precious project.

When I try to run it it fails:

```
02-16 19:56:53.164: E/AndroidRuntime(432): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-16 19:56:53.164: E/AndroidRuntime(432): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity     ComponentInfo{com.test.myapp/com.test.myapp.MyActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.myappcore.MyActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.test.myapp-2.apk]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I've found sometimes Eclipse doesn't actually add the library to the project.properties file.  If so you have to do it by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add the library project not via Project References but via Android > Library in the Properties dialog:

[image]

Add the library project to the list in the bottom right list of this screen.